# Use reduction of order to find a solution of the given nonhomogeneous equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

## Question

Use reduction of order to find a solution of the given nonhomogeneous equation. The indicated function $y_1(x)$ is a solution of the associated homogeneous equation. Determine a second solution of the homogeneous equation and a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation.

$$
y''-4y=2; y_1=e^{-2x}
$$

I am very confused on their free use of "homogeneous" and "nonhomogeneous". This is how I am understanding the question:

"the given nonhomogeneous equation":  $y''-4y=2$

"the associated homogeneous equation": ???

My teacher told me that a homogeneous equation in this context is one that equals zero, however there is none here. also, when I plug $y_1$ into $y''-4y=2$ it is not valid because you get $0=2$.

Comment: $\color{blue}{\text{The associated homogeneous equation: }y''-4y=0}$.

Note that if $\color{blue}{\varphi(x)}$ is a solution to the last homogeneous equation, then $\color{blue}{y=\varphi(x)-\frac{1}{2}}$ is a solution for $$y''-4y=2$$

Answer (score 1):

The homogeneous equation associated with $y''-4y=2$ is $y''-4y=0$. Once you know the solutions $y_1$, $y_2$ of the homogeneous equation, you can easily find the particular solution using the method of variation of parameters: $y(x)=u_1(x)y_1(x)+u_2(x)y_2(x)$. See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx) for more.

Comment: Or just observe that $y=1/2$ is a particular solution,

Comment: Thats a lot quicker. Of course you mean $y=-1/2$

Comment: yes, I did  thanks!

Comment: We haven't learned variation of parameters so I don't know what my teacher will think of if he sees me using this. Is there another way?

Comment: In that case, use Chilango's comment

Comment: @zed111 but how do I use reduction of order correctly here? I declared $y_2=uy_1=ue^{-2x}$. I then found $y_2''$ and plugged this and $y_2$ into the homogeneous equation. After simplifying, I got $u''e^{-2x}=0$. However, even if I make the substitution $w=u'$, I don't know if I am on the right track by doing so. This tells me that $y_2=C_1xe^{-2x}+C_2e^{-2x}$. Does this sound at all on the right track?

Comment: The solution of the homogeneous equation is: $y=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-2x}$. You can easily get these using the characteristic polynomial $r^2-4=0$.